# Is ekert91 more secure than BB84?

Tags: quantum-cryptography

I'm studying quantum cryptography and my question is "simple": 
Is the use of entangled states, like in the Ekert91 protocol, more secure than using not-entangled states like the BB84's ones?

Is easier to detect eavesdropping in Ekert91?

Comment: Hello!  BB84's prepare & measure technique is  easier to currently implement. Both share the same error correction and privacy amplification, but the shifted key rate ratios are different. When you get answers, do not conflate attacks against the hardware with the protocols themselves. A definition of 'security' is going to be the crux.

Comment: @PaulUszak Thanks! I have read about some "hardware" attack like Photon Number Splitting, Trojan Horse, etc. the only one attack I knew that is about the protocol and not the hardware is the "edit & resend"...but this attack can be performed on both the protocols... I just want to know if there is a way for Eve to intercept the key or have information about it without being discovered in just one protocol of the two (and the "attack" should be "hardware independent"...)